# Calling an instance method without creating an instance of class in Python

Tags: python, methods, instance

I read on that instance methods can only be called by creating an instance (object) of the class. But it appears that I can call one without doing so. Check the code below:

```
class Test:
    def func(self): #Instance Method
        print(6)

Test.func(Test) # Here I am calling an instance method without creating an instance of class. How?
```

Please let me know what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: In this case `Test.func("foo")` or `Test.func(None)` would work too, the value of `self` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works because you feed as `self` argument the class itself.

Your function will work as long as you use `self` as class *type* and not as class *instance*, which is very bad practice.

I suggest to use `staticmethod`s for such purposes:

```py
class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def func():
        print(6)

Test.func()
```

or `@classmethod`:

```py
class Test:

    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        print(6)

Test.func()
```

Output:

```py
6
```

Comment: `@classmethod` is better alternative than `@staticmethod`

Comment: Depends on the use case. Neither is necessarily "better", they're just different.

Comment: @SystemSigma_ I want to know that although it is a bad practice but can you call instance methods with class without creating an object of that class?

Comment: @CrazyChucky except static methods are usually considered bad practice, while class methods have valid use-cases.

Comment: @AliMurtaza clearly you "can", based on the piece of code you posted. It "works" because of way Python works, but makes very fragile code.

Comment: @AliMurtaza, your code will work as long as you don't use ``self`` as a class *instance* of ``Test``, but as a class type. Which is very bad practice.

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks :) Can you please explain me briefly what exactly the instance methods are?

Comment: @SystemSigma_ "Your code will work as long as you don't use self as a class instance of Test, but as a class type. " Please elaborate it a bit with code. I am not getting you..

Comment: instance methods are the the standard methods defined in a class - in your example `func` in `Test` class is an instance method. When called on an object, they get the object they are called on passed as a first argument (which is commonly called `self`).

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks,  Is it mandatory to call instance methods with only objects of class?

Comment: It is how they are **supposed** to be used.